# How to prevent from json-server to reload page after post?

Tags: jquery, json-server

I'm using [Json Server](https://github.com/typicode/json-server) for mocking API requests and i'm experiencing an annoying behavior , each post that i'm doing causes the page to reload... i've read their api documentation but didn't came up with anything. I'm using a simple jquery ajax request that looks like this :

```
$.ajax({
url: 'http://localhost:3000/list',
type: 'post',
data: itemObj,

dataType: 'json',

success: function (itemObj) {
 
  todoListArr.push(itemObj);
  createMarkup(); 
  $(this).val(''); // clear input
  return false;

  }
});
```

I've tried e.preventDefault() but it's nothing to do with the ajax call - it's the json-server that causes it... the command that i'm using for running the server is :
npx json-server --watch db.json
tried also
npx json-server

Comment: My bet is this is inside a form. The `return false` inside success callback does not return to the outer function. Similarly if you call `event.preventDefault()` in the `success` it is too late. It will fire long after the event completes

Comment: Thanks - i'm not using form - just a plain input with onKeyPress event - the problem is with the Json Server since any other mocking api works well

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to prevent page reload when using $ajax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66825417/how-to-prevent-page-reload-when-using-ajax)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, if your using VS code try not use the live server extension(disable it), and it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

It may be because of live server extension or something like that refresh html pages if you're using for example vs code live server. Another possibility is if you're using a form and if something inside the form or outside the form is listening to the same submit event that may cause event bubbling so you may try  `e.stopPropagation();` as well.

Comment: Thanks - i've added return false - to stopPropagation got nothing to do with it... the problem is regarding the Json Server since any other mock api works....

Comment: Did you try disabling any live server extension that you may be using on your Ide?

Comment: Thanks, I'm running live server on another port.... Why do you think it should interupt?

Answer (score 0):

I suffered the same problem using VSCode with LiveServer extension and JSON server.

In my case, i had a form sending a post with vanilla AJAX, and every time I submitted the form, the page became reloaded.

Then, I tried to avoid this returning false on the callback method. ie:

```
<form id="forma" onsubmit="postAlumno(); return false;" method="POST">
```

But it wasn´t enough :(

In a casual way, i discovered that **if you run a JSONserver process from other VScode Window the auto reloading stops!**

Other solution, maybe open the page locally -if possible-, without any server.